# How to test factory classes?

Tags: php, unit-testing, design-patterns, testing

Given this class:

```
class MyBuilder {
    public function build($param1, $param2) {

        // build dependencies ...

        return new MyClass($dep1, $dep2, $dep3);
    }
}
```

How can I unit test this class?

Unit-testing it means I want to test its behavior, so I want to test it builds my object with the correct dependencies. However, the `new` instruction is hardcoded and I can't mock it.

For now, I've added the name of the class as a parameter (so I can provide the class name of a mock class), but it's ugly:

```
class MyBuilder {
    public function build($classname, $param1, $param2) {

        // build dependencies ...

        return new $classname($dep1, $dep2, $dep3);
    }
}
```

Is there a clean solution or design pattern to make my factories testable?

Answer (score 4):

Factories are inherently testable, you are just trying to get too tight of control over the implementation.

You would check that you get an instance of your class via `$this->assertInstanceOf()`.  Then with the resulting object, you would make sure that properties are set properly.  For this you could use any public accessor methods or use `$this->assertAttribute*` methods that are available in PHPUnit.

http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.assertions.assertEquals

Many of the common assertions also have the ability to check attributes for protected and private properties.

I wouldn't specify the classname in your parameter list, as your usage is that the factory will only return one type and it is only the dependencies that are changed.  Making it return a mock object type is unnecessary and makes your test more complicated.

The test would end up looking like this:

```
public function testBuild() {
    $factory = new MyBuilder();

    //I would likely put the following into a data provider
    $param1 = 'foo';
    $param2 = 'bar';

    $depen1 = 'boo';
    $depen2 = 'baz';
    $depen3 = 'boz';

    $object = $factory->build($param1, $param2);

    $this->assertInstanceOf('MyClass', $object);

    //Check the object definition
    //This would change depending on your actual implementation of your class
    $this->assertAttributeEquals($depen1, 'attr1', $object);
    $this->assertAttributeEquals($depen2, 'attr2', $object);
    $this->assertAttributeEquals($depen3, 'attr3', $object);
}
```

You are now making sure that your factory returns a proper object.  First by making sure that it is of the proper type.  Then by making sure that it was initialized properly.

You are depending upon the existence of `MyClass` for the test to pass but that is not a bad thing.  Your factory is intended to created `MyClass` objects so if that class is undefined then your test should definitely fail.

Having failing tests while your developing is also not a bad thing.

Comment: but in unit testing, you don't let it touch other units. If you are writing test for factory class, it shouldn't create object of other class in it. dependency should always be mocked. So problem here is that how you can mock something that you aren't passing from outside.

Comment: @Hafiz except the point of a factory is to create other objects.  The tests for a factory class ensures that the correct type of object is created.  These objects aren't dependencies, they are what the function returns.

Comment: yes, got it, my bad. there is no need to mock because it is doing nothing else than creating and returning an object. So we will just assert that type equality.

Answer (score 1):

So what do you want to test?

> so I want to test it builds my object with the correct dependencies.

I do see a problem with this. It's either possible that you can create an object with incorrect dependencies (which should not be the case in the first place or tested in other tests, not with the factory) or you want to test a detail of the factory that you should not test at all.

Otherwise - if it's not mocking the factory what you're looking for - I see no reason why a simple

```
$actual = $subject->build($param1, $param2);
$this->assertInstanceOf('MyClass', $actual);
```

would not make it. It tests the behavior of the factory build method, that it returns the correct type.

See as well [Open-Close-Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)

---

For tests, you can just create your MockBuilder which extends from your Builder:

```
class MyMockBuilder extends MyBuilder {
    public function build($param1, $param2) {

        // build dependencies ...

        return new MyMockClass($dep1, $dep2, $dep3);
    }
}
```

Making the classname a parameter 1:1 seems not practical to me, because it turns the factory over into something different. The creating is a detail of the factory, nothing you externalize. So it should be encapsulated. Hence the MockBuilder for tests. You switch the Factory.

Comment: Well, perhaps then the answer (speaking with PHPUnit) is just `$this->assertInstanceOf('MyClass', $actual);` after invoking the build method on the factory. You either need to mock the factory or you need to test the factories creation value.

Comment: I agree that having the classname as a parameter is not good :S. However I don't get how your solution allows me to test that the dependencies are correct? In your answer, I (the tester) would be overriding the method I want to test.

Comment: `assertInstanceOf` is not enough, I want to test the dependencies given to the constructor of `MyClass`

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli: Test them, but only in the unit-tests of each of those dependencies. A constructor shouldn't be doing any real work either and the factory only needs to return a (abstract) type, so instanceof is working pretty well for that. I also edited the answer, because I have the feeling you want to test in the wrong area which makes it more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: My builder has helper methods to set several "flags", and `build()` returns a configured object. I want to check that my builder does indeed produce an object configured as I asked it. I think it's ok, it's black box testing.

Comment: If `build()` returns a configured object, give that configured object a method that returns it's configuration. Then you can validate if it was configured correctly by comparing the actual against the concrete configuration.

Comment: I don't want to add a method on my object just for the tests. This is breaking encapsulation.

Comment: Well, as I wrote earlier: You don't *need* to because testing constructor parameters would also break encapsulation. It's an internal detail. However, if you do integration testing, then breaking encapsulation can be valid.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you ned to verify two things for that builder:

- the correct instance is returned
- values, that are injected are the right ones.

Checking instance is the easy part. Verifying values needs a bit of trickery.

> <strike>The simples way to do this would be altering the autoloader. You need to make sure that when `MyClass` is requested for autoloader to fetch, instead of `/src/app/myclass.php` file it loads `/test/app/myclass.php`, which actually contains a "transparent" mock (where you with simple getters can verify the values).</strike>
>
> <kbd>bad idea</kbd>

**Update:**

Also, if you do not want to mess with autoloader, you can just at th top of your `myBuilderTest.php` file include the mock class file, which contains definition for `MyClass`.

... this actually seems like a cleaner way.

```
namespace Foo\Bar;
use PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase;

require TEST_ROOT . '/mocks/myclass.php'

class MyBuilderTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function MyBuilder_verify_injected_params_test()
    {
         $target = new MyBuilder;
         $instance = $target->build('a', 'b');

         $this->assertEquals('a', $instance->getFirstConstructorParam(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean, but that's some serious hacking for just testing this. Especially since I have a whole test suite and tricking the autoloader would probably affect the other tests :(

Comment: Including the file -> would also mess the other tests :S

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli, why would it mess with other tests? Each test-class gets called in isolation, AFAIK. Just because you have some file included in `MyBuilderTest` class, does not mean that it will have any impact on 'FooBarTest`. Also, since you are testing the builder and not the product, then the `MyBuilderTest` should not contiain any test that depend on logic in `MyClass`.

Comment: Because the other tests would then also se the mock, not the original class

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli , each test-class is executed in isolation. Anyway, I suspect that your problem is cause by doing computation int the constructor of `MyClass`, because if it contained only assignments, it would be pointless to test.

Comment: No all tests are executed in the same process, classes that are loaded are loaded for all the tests (unless you run phpunit in isolation mode, which I don't want to).

Comment: In that case i have no fckign idea, what are the "mocks" tht you are talking about.

Comment: You say: write a mock class that has the same name than the class the builder will create, so that the builder will create the mock instead of the original class. And I say: if I do that, then I won't be able to use the original class in the other tests because the autoloader won't look for it since this class is already loaded (the mock).

Comment: "I suspect that your problem is cause by doing computation int the constructor of MyClass" No I don't want to test `MyClass`, I want to test `MyClassFactory`. I don't care about the constructor of `MyClass`.