# Dynamic contructor values for unit test in php

Tags: php, phpunit

I am currently in the process of doing some refactoring. The stuff is not done by me. I just have to deal with it.

```
$expected = new instance(0,0,Argument::any());

$result = $this->otherInstance->returnsInstance([]);

$this->assertEquals($expected, $result);
```

**Instance** is some kind of model, which is returned by **otherInstance**. The problem is that the third argument is dynamic and an integer. It can be anything. As you can see, it is mandatory for instantiation of the model. Can this be mocked somehow? How do I set up the test properly?

This does obviously not work ...

```
::__construct() must be of the type integer, object given
```

So, how do I mock this? Or how do I set up the test in such a way as to handle dynamic values? The language level is 7.1, but I want to move to 7.4 soon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test factory classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302156/how-to-test-factory-classes)

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One way to work with different test scenarios is using [Data Providers](https://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers).

In the example below, you set some arbitrary values in the method `provideModelConstructorArguments`. The test `testMyTest` will run twice, one time for each set of values present in the data provider.

```
public function provideModelConstructorArguments()
{
    return [
        [
            'argument1' => 0,
            'argument2' => 1,
            'argument3' => 100
        ],
        [
            'argument1' => 5,
            'argument2' => 3,
            'argument3' => 57
        ]
    ];
}

/**
* @dataProvider provideModelConstructorArguments
**/
public function testMyTest($argument1, $argument2, $argument3)
{
    $expected = new instance($argument1, $argument2, $argument3);

//continue your test code 
}
```

Comment: Nope. That does not work. Let us, for arguments sake, point to a method like **getmypid** or **memory_get_usage**. The the comparison of the instances would differ according to the data in the data provider. I would have done as you said, but it is not a feasible way. I cannot mock it with static values. So, how do I do this in this regard. I know that I did this in an earlier project for a company somehow, but I simply cannot recall the way that I did the proper mocking with Argument::any(). That is why I am asking.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but, if the 3rd argument is random, anything you pass when creating `$expected` in your test, will probably always differ from the instance returned by `$this->otherInstance->returnsInstance([]);`. What if you change your assertion to: `$this->assertInstanceOf(ExpectedModel::class, $result);`?

Comment: Yes, you are right of course. Maybe I have to refrain from actually trying to do a functional test with proper value comparison and go for something less granular. Not that I am (entirely) happy with it, but it appears that is no way around it. I hoped that someone would -- and maybe there still will be -- a way in mocking 1..n random parameters. This is what I have to deal with in another function test. Maybe I can only go for some kind of type measurement and go to the bottom of the actual calculation aspect; which is a pity, as can be imagined. I not sure whether refactoring would solve it.

Comment: I don't know how is your code inside `otherInstance` but it could be done if `instance` is instatiated in a method different than `returnsInstance()`. You could instantiate `$expected` in your test with an arbitrary 3rd arg and mock `otherInstance` partially, setting  the method `otherInstance->methodThatCreateInstance()` to return the `$expected`.

Comment: Still, it wouldn't be a great test case, because you would be passing `$expected` to `otherInstance` just to assert if `returnsInstance` is returning it. I believe that `assertInstanceOf` is enough.